# Closed maps in terms of "thickening fibers"

Tags: general-topology

Recently, [I have asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582313/intuition-for-kuratowski-mrowka-characterization-of-compactness) for intuition for the characterization of compactness of a space $X$ in terms of the closedness of the projection $X\times Y\rightarrow Y$. The wonderful answer I have received includes the following statment:

> - A continuous function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is closed iff for each $y\in Y$ and each open $U\subset X$ with $f^{−1}[{y}]\subset U$ there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ such that $f^{−1}[V]\subset U$.

It seems to me that continuity is not relevant here. Saying $f$ is closed is equivalent to saying $f(U^c)^c$ is open for every open $U\subset X$. But $f(U^c)^c$ is the set of elements of $Y$ whose fibers are all contained in $U$, so to say it is open is equivalent the second part of the statement.

Is this a silly mistake on my part or is continuity really irrelevant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity of $f$ is indeed irrelevant here. Your proof is very short and elegant. And, also not quite unimportant, it is correct.