# Closed maps in terms of lifting properties (analogousy to formally étale morphisms)?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory

In continuation to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622274/closed-maps-in-terms-of-thickening-fibers), where closed maps are characterized by "fiber thickenings", I trying to formulate this fiber thickening condition as some lifting property of $f$ against some class of arrows.

The motivation for this is the definition of formally étale maps as those satisfying a lifting property, which intuitively says étale maps are precisely those along which we may lift infinitesimal tubular neighborhoods. I'm trying to duplicate that definition here.

So the shape of the diagram is as below, but I can't find how to label it.
$$\array{
    \bullet &\longrightarrow& \bullet
    \\
    \downarrow &\nearrow& \downarrow
    \\
    \bullet &\longrightarrow& \bullet
  }$$

Comment: Closed maps can't be defined by a right lifting property: if they could, then the pullback of a closed map would always be a closed map, which is not the case.

Comment: @ZhenLin do closed maps have the left cancellation property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed maps cannot be defined by a right lifting property: if they could, then the pullback of a closed map would always be a closed map, which is not the case.